# How to get difference in dates between to dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a split string **lines="Ram Hue, 134, 20.5.1994, 20.4.2004"**
and I want to get the difference in dates between to dates **20.5.1994** and **20.5.1994**, I tried in JavScript but i'ts not working. Also when trying to extract both dates using
`lines[2] lines[3]` I'm getting wrong outputs

```
var date1 = new Date(lines[2])
var date2 = new Date(lines[3])
var diffDays = parseInt((date2-date1)/(1000*60*60*24),10)
console.log(diffDays)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @MauriceNino   No, My issue was with getting those two dates from the string

Comment: Check this documentation about initializing a Date Object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lines` is a string, `lines[2]` will just get you the character with index 2 within the string. Instead you need to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string before:

```
const arr = lines.split(',');
```

Then you can access both date strings as `arr[2]` and `arr[3]`